# Writing a macro to create a new tab and name that tab based on a cell value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-macro

I would like to have a Macro that generates a new tab and names that tab based on a cell value.

There is a tab called `'Dashboard'!` on which the user enters information in assigned cells. Afterwards, I would like there to be a button that the user clicks, upon which the information from the `'Dashboard'!` is copied to a **new sheet**. That new sheet should be given the name that the user has entered in cell `B2` (the name of the day) and cell `C2` (the date of that day), followed by the word `"Training"`.

I have successfully recorded a Macro that does most of this, but naming the new tab based on a cell value seems impossible. I have manually changed the name of the tab, which shows up in the Macro perfectly. I do not know, however, how to make this name *'dynamic'*.

Thanks in advance for any help, apologies in advance if this question is redundant and/or phrased inadequately.

Comment: Instead of a macro you should use a Google Apps Script trigger. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: Related [sheet name from cell (formatting issue)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/131525/88163)

Comment: Related [Dynamic generation of sheet name from cell content](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84190/88163)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have read the suggested articles and understand that there is a myriad of possibilities out there to enhance Google Sheets. The language in which to write Triggers and further commands eludes me, however. I was hoping that someone could propose a piece of code that I could use in my file. I will try to run the small script that is suggested on one of the referrerd pages, creating new sheets and naming them based on the value of cell A1. Any more help (more to the point) is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

@Rubén has suggested two good topics for you to review. However, both are slightly complicated by other issues (not relevant to your scenario), and "decoding" those aspects could well make the task more complicated than need be.

OTOH, I agree with Ruben that 1) you should use a trigger (or even a menu) to execute the code - that it up to you to investigate and resolve, and 2) you need to learn how to read and write data with scripts; macros are all very well, but they aren't a substitute in this scenario.

```
function wa13477102() {

    // set up the spreadsheet and establish the current sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    // get the name of the current sheet - so that you don't accidentally try and name the new sheet with the same name.
  var oldName = sheet.getName();

    // get the values from Cell B2 and C2
    // Note for the date in Cell C2 we use "getDisplayValue()" for a WYSIWYG value.
  var myday = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var mydate = sheet.getRange("C2").getDisplayValue();

    // get the new name just by joining the two; there are lots of other ways to do this; you can search on Stackoverflow
  var newName = myday+mydate;

    // logic 
    // 1) if the length of the newname is grater than zero - that means there IS a value for newname; it's not just a blank.
    // AND
    // 2) the new name isn't the same as the old name.
  if (newName.toString().length>0 && newName !== oldName) {

    // insert a new sheet and name it with your newname.
    ss.insertSheet(newname);
  }
}
```